# Python3 - Adding User Response to a List Instead of Over-writing Existing Data

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, tuples, user-input

I am trying to write a basic store-front script that loops until the customer says no to the question. Each time there's input of an Item Number, I'm trying to store it and then eventually be able to match those numbers up with the Item Name and the Price (not quite yet, though)...

I am just, now, trying to get it to add to the empty list "item_nums" instead of adding the last entry and over-writing the previous numbers.

## STOREKEEPER

```
products = ['Notebook', 'Atari', 'TrapperKeeper', 'Jeans', 'Insects', 
'Harbormaster', 'Lobotomy', 'PunkRock', 'HorseFeathers', 'Pants', 
'Plants', 'Salami']
prices = ['$4.99', '$99.99', '$89.99', '$3.99', '$2.99', '$299.99', 
'$19.99', '$3.99', '$4.99', '$2.99', '$119.99', '$1.99']
SKUs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10, 11, 12]
item_nums = ()
quantity = []
response = ''

#MORE VARIABLES AND FUNCTIONS WILL GO HERE

print("Jay's House of Rip-Offs\n\n")
titles = ['Item Number', 'Item Name', 'Price']
data = [titles] + list(zip(SKUs, products, prices))

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    line = '|'.join(str(x).ljust(16) for x in d)
    print(line)
    if i == 0:
        print('-' * len(line))

response = str(input("Order products [Y / N]?: "))

while response != 'N':
    item_nums = input("Enter an item number: ")
    SKUs.append(item_nums)
    response = str(input("Order products [Y / N]?: "))
    if response == 'N':
        break
print("Here is the list of items you ordered: ",item_nums[0])
```

Comment: There are a few basic problems with this code that don't need a formal answer. Instead, I suggest you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you strip out the extra stuff, the problem will become more clear. You can also learn to use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) (the Python debugger), or simply use some `print` statements. The main problem is that you are reading a string into `item_nums`, appending that to `SKUs`, and then printing out the first character of the last string read in. `item_nums` is not a list.

Comment: thank you Jim Stewart. i wrote it in pseudo-code a little while ago and realize that i need to let item_nums be what i have SKUs set up to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're appending to `SKU`, you need a new list to track order numbers.

```
orders = []
while str(input("Order products [Y / N]?: ")) != 'N':
    item_nums = input("Enter an item number: ")
    orders.append(item_nums)
print("Here is the list of items you ordered: ", orders)
```